# Created a visual webpart for office 365 and getting error

Tags: office-365, sandbox-solution, client-object-model, visual-studio-2012

This is the error, It's just a simple visual web part i created as sandbox, please guide

> Getting Error Message for Exception System.Security.SecurityException:
>   That assembly does not allow partially trusted callers.

Here are the references,

[image]

Comment: Did you use Sandboxed visual webpart. Normal visual webparts are not allowed in sandbox solutions.

Comment: @Unnie it's visual studio 2012, only gives option for visual webpart then asks for to deploy solution as sandbox or not

Comment: Also you have referenced client object model assemblies.You should be using Microsoft.SharePoint.dll

Comment: :S really ? how come, i thought they are for CSOM

Comment: I suppose you are using CSOM in your webpart then?

Comment: yes, i am Unnie, thats right

Answer (score -1):

We can only use declarative code and Javascript in sandbox solutions.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdev/archive/2014/01/14/deprecation-of-custom-code-in-sandboxed-solutions.aspx

Please remove the Microsoft.SharePoint.Client dlls from the solution and test it.

Comment: ???? if i remove the dll, how my code going to run ?????

Comment: dlls are required to run the custom managed code. If you have custom code then you have to change it to relavent JSOM. Microsoft.SharePoint.Client dlls are nothing to do with JSOM. You can refer one of the example in the below link using JSOM in sandbox solution. http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vstudio/SharePoint-2013-Manage-1f3ac74e.if you remove the dlls from the sandbox project still the solution works.                        Moreover there is a codeplex solution http://officeams.codeplex.com/ which can help you to acheive the functionality using App Model. I hope this helps.

Comment: sorry but who said, I am using JSOM ? :-(

Comment: however, thanks for office arms link, it is helpful, if you add link to your answer, i will upvote your answer, thank

Comment: Apologies for the broken link, here is the correct one http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-2013-Manage-1f3ac74e